# getting background colour to work on div

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
height:1200px;
width:800px;
overflow: auto;
background:green;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;

}

.sidebar {
background:grey;
position:absolute;
left:10%;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
width:20%;
height:100%;
float:left;
}

.content {
background:blue;
position:absolute;
left:30%;
right:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
width:70%;
float:left;
}

body {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Steven game dev</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
         <br>
          <a href="page2.html">About</a>
          <br>
          <a href="page3.html">Blog</a>
          <br>
          <a href="page2.html">Videos</a>
          <br>
          <a href="page2.html">Pictures</a>
          <br>
          <a href="page2.html">Contact</a>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 </div>
 </div>
</body>

 
</html>
```

Hi all I'm new so go easy on me. I decided to make up a quick website something I haven't done in years and it turns out I literally forgot everything but I thought it would be easy enough to slide back in. I was wrong for some reason I cant add a background colour to one of my Divs. the div is inside a container div which could be the reason I'm having trouble but I'm fairly sure that shouldn't be an issue having done many times before. The div in question is my sidebar I don't understand why it's being difficult but I've tried many things to remedy it and I cant get it to work. Please excuse the sloppy nature of my css I was just quickly trying to block out the divs so that I could get a visual of what I was doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm sure it's something silly that I have missed but this is basic stuff should be easy.

Comment: Viewing your code snippet only shows the grey container, not the orange sidebar. Viewing your code in a fiddle shows the orange and hides the grey, strange. Anyways, try removing the grey background color and see if orange comes through. Note, I find borders easier for identifying element sizes as they don't overlap like background color will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously, this is a mystery, but I have got it working. Here is the solution:

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;
}
```

“But wait”, I hear you say, “that’s the same code!”. Apparently not. Between the `width: 50%;` and the `background-color: orange;` is a character which I cannot see, but which stopped the background colour working.

When testing the snippet, I ended up deleting and re-typing the code, which is something I do when I get desperate.

Comment: Thanks it really is strange I think notepad ++ is trolling me because I hand typed all of this and I can't see any hidden characters either think I'll switch back to good old regular notepad see if that changes anything seems to be everything I typed doesn't work but when I paste things they do thanks again for the help much appreciated.

Comment: That is so weird switched to notepad and suddenly everything works!?

Comment: @moderategamer Been there, done that, bought the post card. Notepad++ is normally very good (I don’t use Windows normally, so I don’t have any recent experience). Sometimes re-typing highlights a typo, but sometimes there’s just this pesky invisible character. Out of curiosity, it might be worth showing invisible characters in N++ to test that theory. If this answered your question, would you care to accept the answer?

Comment: How do I do that? I have new problems though if you wouldn't mind helping I got a trial of dreamweaver so that I could better visualise what I'm doing and it would seem for some reason my wrapper div isn't containing my other divs and I'm not sure why the other divs should always fit as their size are created using %. I'll post the new code in the question.

Comment: sorry don't really know how to use this forum yet is there a way to post code in a comment?

Comment: Sorry for commenting so much but I edited the original post to show my new code as I couldn't figure out how to do it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You had whitespace characters before background-color: orange. So the browser thought the name was [whitespace][whitespace]background-color which it doesn't recognize. I know this because I looked at the #sidebar element in devtools and got `unrecognized rule: background-color` which only makes sense if there was some invisible white-space in that string. Turns out your sloppy css writing was inexcusable!

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: orange;
  float:left;
}

#container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;    
  float:left;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}

#content  {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styledesign.css"/>
</head>
 <title>
Steven game dev!
 </title>

<div id ="container">
<div id ="sidebar">
<a href="page2.html">Home</a>
<a href="page2.html">About</a>
<a href="page2.html">Blog</a>
<a href="page2.html">Videos</a>
<a href="page2.html">Pictures</a>
<a href="page2.html">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id ="content">

 <h1>Welcome to my website take a look around </h1>
 <p>
 I'm a drop out game developer from the University of Abertay Dundee and I've decided to give it another go. 
 Watch me learn game development along the way as I slowly build my first 3d game using the Unreal Engine 4.
 </p>


  
 <p>
 Here is some work I have been doing on particles. As you may have noticed the goal was to try and recreate the particles from the Legends of Zeld: Windwaker. 
 I'm still learning but it's a start the basic principles are there still have to work on the debris that scatters of from the explosion with trails of smoke 
 following behind using Tails in ue4 particles editor.
 </p>
 
</div>
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Most additional spaces in CSS are ignored. The only significant spaces are (a) some spaces in selectors which have the effect of a child selector, such as `a b {}` and (b) spaces in properties which are inside quotes, such as `font-family: "Lucida Grande";`. Spaces around `background-color` won’t have an impact.

Comment: @Manngo fair enough, it must have been another whitespace character then. Because when I looked in developer tools I saw `unrecognized rule: background-color`. Once I deleted the whitespace surrounding `background-color` the browser recognized it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a sidebar navigation menu try my codes below. And I also recommend the following https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp and http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/cxQGc/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a href="page2.html">Home</a>
            <br>
            <a href="page2.html">About</a>
            <br>
            <a href="page2.html">Blog</a>
            <br>
            <a href="page2.html">Videos</a>
            <br>
            <a href="page2.html">Pictures</a>
            <br>
            <a href="page2.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
.sidebar {
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 178px;
}

.content {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 178px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I still don't get why it's not working though any thoughts.